# How Can I access any text or XML file using AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, text-files

```
<div id="new"></div>
<button id="btn" onclick="changeContent('C:\Users\MarshMellow\Desktop\whatever.txt', newFunc)">Click Here!!</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeContent(url,callFunc) {  
    var xhttp;`declaration'
    xhttp.onreadystatechange= function () {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            callFunc(this);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET","C:\Users\MarshMellow\Desktop\whatever.txt",true);
    xhttp.send();
}
function newFunc(xhttp) {`Function call`
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
}
```

Still no Output. Seems like the AJAX call is not working properly.

Comment: Please post the code instead of an image of the code. Also do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Also from your image it looks like `callFunc` is called but not defined.

Comment: Your browser probably won't allow loading local files via XHR.

Comment: File URIs look like this: `file:///C/Users/MarshMellow/Desktop/whatever.txt` and will only work if your HTML file is also loaded from local file.

Comment: I couldn't do that pasting of code in order. Can you identify the problem?

Comment: Initialize your xhttp like this `var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: <div id="new"></div>
<button id="btn" onclick="changeContent('file:///C/Users/MarshMellow/Desktop/whatever.txt', newFunc)">Click Here!!</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeContent(url,callFunc) { 
 var xhttp;
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   callFunc(this);
  }
 };
 xhttp.open("GET","file:///C/Users/MarshMellow/Desktop/whatever.txt",true);
 xhttp.send();
}
function newFunc(xhttp) {
 document.getElementById("new").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
}

Comment: I initialized it. No issues from that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be working with static files on your computer, you need a server to make a request to if you want to make an ajax call.
Try Setting up a server and putting those files in the site's directory if you want to use an ajax call so bad.
Another option is using a file input and the [filereader api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)